# how to separate words into different increasing letter combinations

Tags: python, list

I want to slice a word inside a list and print it into separate parts.
so if my word is pink and hello then how can I get the results.

```
word = [pink]
return [p,  pi, pin, pink]

word2 = [hello]
return [h, he, hel, hell, hello]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the different prefixes of a word

```
def prefixes(word):
    return [word[:i + 1] for i in range(len(word))]

print(prefixes("hello"))  # ['h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello']
print(prefixes("pink"))   # ['p', 'pi', 'pin', 'pink']
```